# Loading multiple images into R for manipulation

Tags: r, image, edge-detection

Currently I am trying to get 100+ images (sequenced) loaded into R and transformed by imager by deriche.  I've tried:

```
files <- list.files(path="C:/Users/amarchand/Desktop/TVideos", pattern=".png$",all.files=T, full.names=F, no.. = T)
```

This works fine, and then I enter:

```
PNG=lapply(files,readPNG)
```

Once these lines are entered, I go to do

```
im.xedges <- deriche(PNG,2,order=2,axis="x")
```

And I get:

```
Error in deriche(PNG, 2, order = 2, axis = "x") : 
Not compatible with requested type: [type=list; target=double].
```

Is there a line of code that I am missing or is there a code that works better than what I have?

Comment: Please CTRL+K your code, for a better output.

Comment: Where does `deriche` come from? You should specify any packages that are needed to help

Comment: deriche comes from imager package.  Right now I am working with imager, png, magick, EBImage, and bioimagetools.